# How to compute the series $\sum\limits_{x=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{y=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{z=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^x(2^{x+y}+2^{x+z}+2^{z+y})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

How to compute the series $\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^\infty\sum_{y=0}^\infty\sum_{z=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^x(2^{x+y}+2^{x+z}+2^{z+y})}$ ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

By **symmetry**, the sum $S$ of this triple series $$
S=\sum_{x,y,z}\frac{1}{2^x\cdot(2^{x+y}+2^{x+z}+2^{z+y})}$$ is also
$$
S=\sum_{x,y,z}\frac{1}{2^\color{red}{y}\cdot(2^{x+y}+2^{x+z}+2^{z+y})}=\sum_{x,y,z}\frac{1}{2^\color{red}{z}\cdot(2^{x+y}+2^{x+z}+2^{z+y})}.
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\frac1{2^x}+\frac1{2^y}+\frac1{2^z}=\frac{2^{x+y}+2^{x+z}+2^{z+y}}{2^{x+y+z}}.
$$
Hence, summing these three equivalent formulas for $S$, one gets
$$
3S=\sum_{x,y,z}\frac1{2^{x+y+z}}=\left(\sum_{x}\frac1{2^x}\right)^3,
$$
and, finally,
$$
S=\frac13\cdot2^3=\frac83.
$$
More generally, for every absolutely convergent series $\sum\limits_x\frac1{a_x}$,
$$
\sum_{x,y,z}\frac{1}{a_x\cdot(a_xa_y+a_xa_z+a_za_y)}=\frac13\left(\sum_x\frac{1}{a_x}\right)^3.
$$

Comment: That, sir, is very nice.

Comment: Symmetry is essential here.

Comment: Awesome! +1 $\;$

Comment: Always try to look for symmetry when dealing with double, triple sums ... $\text{nice}^2$ (+1)

Comment: wow nice answer ...

Comment: If I'm right yesterday I've observed 20 downvotes votes in your profile in a recent day that I believe that were removed, and today I've observed that also you was downvoted massively (25 downvotes) also this last Mar 15, you should not communicate it with the purpose that these downvotes are removed?

Comment: @user243301 Indeed March 15 my account received a spat of 23 downvotes in a 5 minutes span. These were signalled to the mods and dealt with. If another pack of 20 downvotes occurred recently, I must have missed it. Thanks for the comment anyway.